# Can we have in/voluntary Meta suspensions on other sites without suspension on the main sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, per-site-meta, account-suspension

For the purposes of this discussion, I am referring to Main sites and Meta sites, as sites other than Stack Overflow or Stack Overflow Meta.

Some users contribute successfully on SE sites, but not well on the Meta sites. Some suspensions can result from  activity on Meta and not the main site. I am suggesting this, as rather than *throwing the baby out with the bathwater*, so to speak, if suspensions from Meta could be separated, when there are no problems with contributions on the main site, but just in Meta.

People can have chat suspensions, individual site suspensions. Can we please have Meta suspensions for individual sites, without the main site suspension?

For some people the issues for account suspensions, are borne from participation in Meta and blocking the site (with a site blocker) does not assist in the user's overall contributions, as it is important to keep up with Meta, when you're very active on a SE site.

This may be a good way to manage some site infractions without leading to permanent problems.

Comment: Just don't go onto those sites if you don't want to.  It would consume a *lot* of both moderator and developer time for a feature that is unlikely to be used almost at all.

Comment: Use a site blocker yourself. There is plenty of software out there help you keep your self-discipline.

Comment: @Skippy [Yes, even "small" features consume a lot of time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx)

Comment: You are not the first one to request something like this. I recall users asking for a suspension because they are somehow addicted and it interfered with their activities. The thing is however that suspensions are bad. And they are a black mark on you and your participation. You don't want a suspension. If you seriously have trouble containing yourself, perhaps that needs work. But that's not a software update.

Comment: @Skippy You are at full leisure to read and not contribute; we don't mind at all. However, if _you_ find _yourself_ incapable of refraining, then that is not our problem to handle. Also, please consider _why_ you were suspended, because suspensions aren't handed out for normal, friendly (if often opinionated) Meta participation.

Comment: I would think the *opposite* would actually be more important.  We have some users who need to be banned from a main site, because their "contributions" suck for some reason.  Allowing them to ask questions on meta seems appropriate, however, so they can ask why they've been suspended.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The premise here isn't really off - I have personally encountered enough instances where great contributors on the main site tend to not be at their best when they find themselves in a heated meta discussion. This is sort of expected, as great contributors tend to be really passionate when it comes to the sites that they enjoy.

That said, there's a number of reasons that we can't implement this, most are mainly technical. The way that we handle accounts just doesn't lend well to this, as child meta sites *aren't* separate sites as far as the system is concerned. It would add fragility to a part of the system that we *really* can't touch without very compelling reasons.

We also don't want to institute a feature that gives people the impression that they can troll and lollygag on child meta sites to their heart's content without worry that something will happen to their main account. You weren't doing that, but .. it's a real and valid concern. If moderators have *no choice* but to suspend both meta and main site access in order to stop disruptive behavior, well, there's little argument to be had when it happens.

The other thing is self-imposed suspensions aren't really any better than software or hardware that prevents you from accessing certain things. As you technically didn't do anything *wrong* when preemptively suspended at your own request, it's kind of difficult to not reinstate you after a subsequent request. That's .. not a position we'd like to put our community moderators in, and I'm sure one that they appreciate not having to deal with.

I'm not *as* opposed to these types of requests when it comes to chat, but I don't see much utility in them for the same reasons I gave above.

I'm declining, but on the basis of implementation concerns more than fundamental or philosophical. I see what this is reaching for, and see some value in it. It's just not something that fits in to the network so well.

Comment: No problems Tim, I didn't expect it to be approved, but thought it might be a good post to have here as a reference, given the background discussion regarding such topics.

Comment: @Skippy It's been touched on a few times, but I don't think ever really raised as a request / for consensus. You got a share of down votes here, but the idea isn't too far fetched - it would be useful in certain instances where the suspensions _were not_ voluntary. There's just too much baggage that would go along with implementing it.

Answer (score 9):

Meta accounts are synced from the main accounts. It used to be possible to suspend a user only on meta, but rather strange things happened when the main account was synced then. This was not an intended feature, and meta-only suspension was rather broken. The solution to that was to disable meta-only suspension entirely.

Suspension is a disciplinary action, it is not meant as a feature for users that want to block themselves from a certain site. It has been used that way occasionally in the past, but that was entirely by discretion of whoever handled the request, moderators and SE employees are not obliged to fulfill a self-suspension request.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to improve it as a feature request (the tag was edited by a CM).. so you may want to have a look at that. I apologise for the change after you wrote your answer ty

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of browser add-ons that will let you block content from a list of sites that you specify.

This one may be just what you're after:

**[Idderall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/idderall/?src=hp-dl-promo)**

> Idderall lets you specify blocked sites, a block schedule, and best of
>   all: a deterrent to keep you from accessing settings and unblock
>   sites. Idderall has 3 possible deterrents. What will stop you from
>   going on blocked sites? Perhaps money will talk to you (losing money
>   that is), if not, maybe an intervention from friends, or the potential
>   for being embarrassed on facebook will stop you. If you need to access
>   a blocked sites or change your settings, you will need to suffer your
>   chosen deterrent. Idderall is not simple to deactivate like other
>   productivity tools. Idderall cannot be uninstalled or deactivated
>   while a block is active.

Comment: Yes I am aware of these, I have edited my question.. so that these side issues are not addressed.

Comment: @Skippy I'm not opposed to Meta specific bans, Ive encountered a number of users that seem to get on perfectly well on the main sites, but seem to have issues on Meta sites. Voluntary bans on the other hand seem a little unnecessary, users should be responsible for limiting their own participation if need be.

Comment: yes, but one of the CMs editd this to be a feature request, so I've edited it to be a better quality post, taken out personal references.. and so this answer is not really relevant anymore.. sorry to edit it (probably) while you were writing this. I didn't downvote, just let you know cheers

Comment: @Skippy On a side note, its good to see you around again.